# Segmentation fault when running scipy interpolate

Tags: python, scipy

(edit to avoid points on a line issue)
Running the following code:

```
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator
import numpy as np

points = np.array([[ 0,  0],
                   [1,  0],
                   [ 0,  1]])

values = np.array([-3, 8, -2])
ip = LinearNDInterpolator(points, values)
```

on my computer produces the output

> Segmentation fault: 11

To try to fix it, I recently uninstalled and reinstalled numpy and scipy such that

scipy.**version**
'1.3.3'
numpy.**version**
'1.17.4'

But no luck

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily an answer but just more info, when I execute that exact code I get this as output all as error colour:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tadhgmcdonald-jensen/Documents/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    interp = LinearNDInterpolator(pts, z, fill_value= np.nan)
  File "interpnd.pyx", line 248, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator.__init__
  File "qhull.pyx", line 1833, in scipy.spatial.qhull.Delaunay.__init__
  File "qhull.pyx", line 355, in scipy.spatial.qhull._Qhull.__init__
scipy.spatial.qhull.QhullError: QH6154 Qhull precision error: Initial simplex is flat (facet 1 is coplanar with the interior point)

While executing:  | qhull d Q12 Qbb Qc Qt Qz
Options selected for Qhull 2015.2.r 2016/01/18:
  run-id 923456758  delaunay  Q12-no-wide-dup  Qbbound-last  Qcoplanar-keep
  Qtriangulate  Qz-infinity-point  _pre-merge  _zero-centrum  Qinterior-keep
  Pgood  _max-width  2  Error-roundoff 5.5e-15  _one-merge 3.9e-14
  Visible-distance 1.1e-14  U-coplanar-distance 1.1e-14  Width-outside 2.2e-14
  _wide-facet 6.7e-14

precision problems (corrected unless 'Q0' or an error)
      2 flipped facets

The input to qhull appears to be less than 3 dimensional, or a
computation has overflowed.

Qhull could not construct a clearly convex simplex from points:
- p1(v3):     2     3  0.71
- p3(v2):     2     3     2
- p2(v1):     3     4   1.8
- p0(v0):     1     2 5.6e-17

The center point is coplanar with a facet, or a vertex is coplanar
with a neighboring facet.  The maximum round off error for
computing distances is 5.5e-15.  The center point, facets and distances
to the center point are as follows:

center point        2        3    1.122

facet p3 p2 p0 distance=    0
facet p1 p2 p0 distance=    0
facet p1 p3 p0 distance=    0
facet p1 p3 p2 distance=    0

These points either have a maximum or minimum x-coordinate, or
they maximize the determinant for k coordinates.  Trial points
are first selected from points that maximize a coordinate.

The min and max coordinates for each dimension are:
  0:         1         3  difference=    2
  1:         2         4  difference=    2
  2:  5.551e-17         2  difference=    2

If the input should be full dimensional, you have several options that
may determine an initial simplex:
  - use 'QJ'  to joggle the input and make it full dimensional
  - use 'QbB' to scale the points to the unit cube
  - use 'QR0' to randomly rotate the input for different maximum points
  - use 'Qs'  to search all points for the initial simplex
  - use 'En'  to specify a maximum roundoff error less than 5.5e-15.
  - trace execution with 'T3' to see the determinant for each point.

If the input is lower dimensional:
  - use 'QJ' to joggle the input and make it full dimensional
  - use 'Qbk:0Bk:0' to delete coordinate k from the input.  You should
    pick the coordinate with the least range.  The hull will have the
    correct topology.
  - determine the flat containing the points, rotate the points
    into a coordinate plane, and delete the other coordinates.
  - add one or more points to make the input full dimensional.
```

I don't know enough about scipy to know exactly what is going on but is it possible your input is invalid and you just happen to not get a meaningful output on your machine? this might be relevant to report to scipy as a bug.

`scipy.version.version == '1.3.1' and numpy.version.version == '1.17.3'`

Comment: These are good suggestions, thank you!  Maybe I've found an existing bug report: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11088

Answer (score 1):

As the error message in the other answer says: your 3 points do not form a triangle:

```
y
^
4       p4       (3,4)
3    p2          (2,3)
2 p1             (1,2)
1
0  1  2  3  > x
```

They are on a line. Simplices are the name of generic, n-dimensional "triangles", your 2D points are supposed to form an actual triangle (when there are only 3 of them).

So change absolutely any coordinate in the input, and it may work.

Comment: Should this code work then ```from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator
import numpy as np

points = np.array([[ 0,  0],
                   [1,  0],
                   [ 0,  1]])

values = np.array([-3, 8, -2])
ip = LinearNDInterpolator(points, values)```  it still seg faults for me

Comment: @PaulFleming the fact that you have a crash instead of the error message may still indicate that you found a bug. Based on "Segmentation fault" I would guess you are on a Linux/Unix variant. Is it, or the hardware, anything "esoteric"?

Comment: mac, maybe same as the person in the github comments here:  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11088

Answer (score 0):

A good solution seems to be set up a clean conda enviornment.  This issue could derive from the particular way python and scipy are installed (combo of Python 3.7 from Homebrew + SciPy 1.3.x/1.4.x installed with pip):

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11088